# Spark stopped generating driver logand event logs, only executor logs are generated

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using logging on my databricks clusters and I am sending my log data to blob container which I have mounted on my cluster (Cluster Configuration -> Advanced Options -> Logging -> Mounted Path).

Earlier, all the logs were getting generated but after some day (maybe because of some change) there are no logs being generated on log4j console of databricks.

I checked the same on blob container as well there also only executor logs are being logged
[Blob Log Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQTyO.png)

I tried recreating the same issue on some other cluster, but there I could find all the logs are getting generated as expected.

[Blob log Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wnm40.png)

Answer (score 0):

This may occur if the **SAS of your Blob storage expires** after mounting with databricks.

To trouble shoot this, create two clusters and store one cluster's logs in dbfs and another in mounted blob with specified time for expiration of SAS.


[image]


After expiration check the logs stored in blob and dbfs. **If logs are not storing in only blob this issue because of SAS expiration**. If logs not storing in **both dbfs and blob**, then there is an issue with the workspace for cluster logs.

My suggestion is trying with **new databricks workspace** and if there is no issue with logs in both dbfs and blob, you can try [Diagnostic logging in Azure Databricks - Azure Databricks | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/account-settings/azure-diagnostic-logs)